# An error in accessing a data member of a union

Tags: c++, unions

I keep getting an error message "error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char[7] to [30]" when accessing the employee name. I know that only one data member of the union can be accessed at one time. Please, help. Thank you! Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

union employee
{
    char name[30];
    int ID;
    float salary;
};
int main()
{
    union employee emp; 
    emp.name="Tibebu";
    cout<<"Employee name: "<<emp.name<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `emp.name="Tibebu";` You need to use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) here.

Comment: Why on earth would you use a `union` for this? Your code says that an `employee` is either a `name`, an `ID`, or a `salary`, which makes no sense.

Comment: And please use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays. They're much easier to use and much safer.

Comment: `I know that only one data member of the union can be accessed at one time.` is not accurate. You can access any member any time, but of course you need to know what you are doing / expecting.

Comment: Hey Jonny, thanks for replying. Accessing a data member through structure doesn't require the use of the strcpy() function. The striking difference between structure and union is that accessing all data members at a time vs not being possible to access them at a time. I really don't get it why I have to use strcpy in the union. thanks

Comment: @Tibo The striking difference between structure and union is that all its data members share the same space so that changing one of the will also change the others!

Comment: @Tibo And the reason your program doesn't work is because you have to use `strcpy` for copying C-style-strings. It has nothing to do with the union.

Comment: Thanks comments are helpful. I fixed the issue based your suggestions.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of "only one data member can be accessed at a time." A `union` _only every has one member in existence_. You as a programmer are responsible for tracking which member that is and not accessing others while they are not within their lifetime. `union`s are used to represent relationships like "MyUnion is exactly one of X or Y or Z or ...". A `struct` or `class` on the other hand has _all_ members active at once, and represents a relationship like `MyStruct _has_ an X _and_ a Y _and_ a Z _and_ ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that the object is a member of a union. The problem is that you're trying to assign an array. And arrays are not assignable.

To modify an array, you must assign its elements. There are standard functions for copying multiple elements between arrays.